# Memorising a value from a push button

Tags: verilog

I am trying to do this in Verilog:
when a button gets pressed (goes into state 1), I need a variable to be set to 1, and remain like that till I change it.

My code is:

```
always@(button)
begin
if(button==1) begin
var1=1;
end
end
```

But what I seem to get is that the var is set to 1 the whole program.
How do I achieve my goal in a different way???

Comment: you said: *till i change it*. How did you change it? there is no code which would reset the 'var' in your example. BTW, do not use 'var', it is a keyword in system verilog.

Comment: I used a different identificator in the original file. The whole code is too long to post. I have another always block (a long one) that within a certain condition sets it to 0.

Comment: Because var1 has no alternative value in the code above, it will always get assigned to 1. For example if button == 1, var1 gets assigned 1. Now say button == 0, the 'if' check would fail but you haven't assigned an alternative value for var1 so it remains at 1 (you have inferred a latch here). That being said, A button can only have 2 states... 0 or 1. So if you are saying you want var1 to be 1 when button == 1 and  0 when button == 0 it sounds like you want:
var1 = button
But that trivial so I suspect we're missing something as to the intent of the code above.

Comment: Please see this link to learn what it means to show a complete yet minimal example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: as a general rule, you should not set a var1 to a particular value in one always block and reset it in another. It might result in a race, which i assume you got. Always do full set of assignments in a single always block. Also stop using always blocks with sensitivity lists. Use `always @*` instead. This way you will not miss inputs.

Comment: acjrm125, wow thanks that was the problem. I managed to incorporate that into my code. It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons that you are getting always 1 might be, if the button is on the board, and you assigned that as an input, then they generally give output HIGH when not pressed and LOW when pressed. If that is the case use `if(button == 0)` as the condition.

As you mentioned in commands you were using another always block to change the value of the variable, however you should not be able to change the same variable from two different always blocks. Hopefully we can find solutions that can solve your problem.

If your design is synchronous and clocked (generally it is the case in practical hardware designs), you can have something like this (it is practical if your clock has frequency that is larger than 10Hz):

```
module memorize_pb(

input clk,
// you can have some other inputs here for the remaining part of your code
input button

);

reg stored_variable;
// other registers if used
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(button == 1) begin //if the first reason is not the case
stored_variable <= 1'b1;
end
// other parts of your code and conditions which resets your variable
end //end of always block
endmodule
```

**Note: For this code to work, you have to press the pushbutton for longer time than clock period which is practically the case.**

if the design is asynchronous, just include the button in your sensitivity list and write the code in the same always block.